# How to zoom into a specific area of a DirectShow window?

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

[image]

I'm trying to zoom into the area of the DirectShow window between Marker A and Marker B(It's a RangeBar) which represent the width of the video window.
I've tried using SetWindowPosition but all that does is move the video window around.

I'm new to DirectShow, please help !

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IVMRMixerControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface of the renderer to zoom in to a part of the video.

You need to switch the filter to "mixing-mode" (before you connect the filter) by calling `IVMRFilterConfig::SetNumberOfStreams` (2). Connect the Renderer. Now you can set the rect you want to show with a call to `IVMRMixerControl::SetOutputRect`. You need to provide the rectange you want see with normalized values. This means, if you want to zoom in you will set `{-0.5, -0.5, 1.5, 1.5}` and if you want to zoom back you will set `{0, 0, 1, 1}`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I spent a week trying to figure it out. Also this [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/b54bfa3d-bfd9-4159-a178-1c921ae20f0d) helped me too.